# VBA how to display real time clock in a userform?

Tags: vba, excel

So I need to display a real-time clock on my form but I am not sure how. I do know that the code:

```
TimeValue(Now)
```

will give me the current time, but I am not sure how to continually display this on my form.

I have an idea which is to put this code inside of a loop as follows:

```
Dim bool As Boolean
bool = True
Do While bool = True
    Label1.Caption = TimeValue(Now)
Loop
```

However I am not sure where to put this code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue others were having with the given code in the chosen answer. I removed the `latesttime` line and i changed `Label1.caption = Now()` to use `Time()` instead.

```
Sub DisplayCurrentTime()
    Dim nextSecond As Date

    nextSecond = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

    Label1.Caption = Time()

    Application.OnTime _
        Procedure:="DisplayCurrentTime", _
        EarliestTime:=nextSecond
End Sub
```

I then called this in my `userform_initialize` function. `Label1.caption` was changed to the appropriate label on my `userform`.

Comment: I tried the above code; however it gives an error : "Cannot run the macro… the macro may not be available in this workbook". I Tried to make the Sub as Public, still no luck. I am calling the DisplayCurrentTime() in the Public Sub UserForm_Activate().

Please advice to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Mufaddal, try to set the macro you want to run in a module and call/update the userform by the name. So label1.caption will be something like: Userform1.label1.caption = Time()

Answer (score 7):

Excel has [the `OnTime` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195809%28v=office.11%29.aspx) that allows you to schedule the execution of any procedure.

Just use it to schedule a one-second rhythm.

```
Sub DisplayCurrentTime()
  Dim nextSecond As Date

  nextSecond = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

  Label1.Caption = Now()

  Application.OnTime _
    Procedure:="DisplayCurrentTime", _
    EarliestTime:=nextSecond, _
    LatestTime:=nextSecond
End Sub
```

Start the loop by calling `DisplayCurrentTime()` once, for example in the initialize method of your form.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this isn't working but it's not updating the label. (btw you're missing an underscore after `Procedure:="DisplayCurrentTime",`)

Comment: @Brad Thanks, the `_` is fixed. -- Does it compile? Have you set breakpoints/`Debug.Print` calls to see what it's doing? Can you try without the `LatestTime` parameter? Is the `DisplayCurrentTime()`  public in your UserForm module? Also, please try the fully qualified method name (i.e. `"MyProject.UserForm1.DisplayCurrentTime"`).

Comment: Everything compiles. As far as I can tell it's not actually setting the timer. When I run it (`DisplayCurrentTime` called in the `Initialize` event) no error but the label is only set once. If I step through it I get the error `The Macro may not be available in this workbook of all macros may be disabled`. The file is saved as an xlsm.

Comment: @Brad See above (*Also, please try the fully qualified method name (i.e. `"MyProject.UserForm1.DisplayCurrentTime"`*) - Have you done this? There also were a few more questions.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did try a fully qualified name. I tried making the sub public, too. Same results.

Comment: @Brad Does the fully qualified method name work when you try it manually - i.e. when the form is running and you execute it via the direct window?

Comment: I tried `Evaluate("UserForm1.DisplayCurrentTime")` while it was running but can you execute code in the immediate window while a form is not stopped at a breakpoint? Needless to say it did nothing. I'm generally confused here. This seems like the ideal answer. I'm not sure why it isn't happening!

Comment: @Brad Ah, I see what's wrong. The `OnTime()` method can only see public procedures (which includes normal modules, but excludes class modules like `UserForm`). The missing bit is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562913/timer-on-user-form-in-excel-vba, including a nicer implementation.

Comment: Looks like that'll do it! Surprisingly complicated.

Comment: @Brad There are third party Timer ActiveX components (and VB6 has a timer component of its own) but if you want to do it with VBA on-board means, that's as good as it will get, I'm afraid.

Comment: ya it looks pretty complex. i want my userform to call the displaytime() function which is in a normal module. that post looks like its the other way around. the original code you posted broke for me too, but it looks like its on the right track

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your atempt would be, that you are effectively creating an infinite loop.

Your Excel would use up quite some CPU-Time and might even block user-input, because it would excecute your while-statements, as fast as it can.

Look at this example http://www.andypope.info/vba/clock.htm or at the solutions in this post [How do I show a running clock in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11867225/1370465)

They should help you.

At least you should include a `DoEvents` statement in your loop.