# Excel VBA Keep Userform Timer running when Userform or Excel are closed

Tags: vba, excel

Recently I've managed to find some code regarding a timer on a userform, my problem is that I need to keep the timer running even if the userform or excel file is closed... can someone take a look at the code and provide some feedback? My userform is: optionsForm

```
Dim dteStart As Date, dteFinish As Date  
Dim dteStopped As Date, dteElapsed As Date  
Dim boolStopPressed As Boolean, boolResetPressed As Boolean

Private Sub Reset_Timer_Click()  
dteStopped = 0  
dteStart = 0  
dteElapsed = 0  
Tech_Timer = "00:00:00"  
boolResetPressed = True  
End Sub  

Private Sub Start_Timer_Click()  
Start_Timer:  
dteStart = Time  
boolStopPressed = False  
boolResetPressed = False  
    Timer_Loop:  
           DoEvents  
             dteFinish = Time  
             dteElapsed = dteFinish - dteStart + dteStopped  
    If Not boolStopPressed = True Then  
        Tech_Timer = dteElapsed  
    If boolResetPressed = True Then GoTo Start_Timer  
    GoTo Timer_Loop  
Else  
    Exit Sub  
End If  
End Sub  

Private Sub Stop_Timer_Click()  
boolStopPressed = True  
dteStopped = dteElapsed  
End Sub  

Private Sub optionsForm_Initialize()  
Tech_Timer = "00:00:00"  
End Sub
```

Comment: Just an idea - if the excel file is closed, save the value of the form in a cell of excel and then continue from it when it is opened. Would it work like this?

Comment: Ye, no problem with that.... I can create and hide a new tab, sheet1 for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the timer is not that it runs, but that it remembers a point in time and can give you a difference between this point and the current moment. If you ask for this difference every second, then it would look like it is running like a watch.

Something like this would be a good start. In the `xl_main` write the following:

```
Option Explicit

Dim dtime As Date

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Cells(1, 1).Value = dtime
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If Cells(1, 1).Value = 0 Then
        dtime = Now
    Else
        dtime = CDate(Cells(1, 1))
    End If

End Sub
```

You may play around it and make it better as you wish. E.g. you may find a way to reset `dtime` or anything similar.

Comment: Thks for the comment and that important piece of code, but how do i post it in the userform? Can I do something like: Tech_Timer = dtime? , I mean, directly in that label in the userform?

Comment: More like `Tech_Timer = cdate(now-dtime)`

Comment: ok, I figured what to change :) however need to think a bit more over this because I have several userforms and each of them needs to take individual timers. this way, they all get the same timer

Answer (score 1):

"Something" needs to be running to handle the timer procedure so if you want to use VBA then Excel can't be "closed" *per se*, however you could make it appear closed.

An obvious option is to minimize the Excel window (before showing the userform) with the [*`WindowState` property*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-windowstate-property-excel):

```
Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
```

...or, hide the Excel window completely with the [*`Visible` property*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-windowstate-property-excel):

```
Application.Visible = False
```

...or if the issue is that you need a "fresh" copy of Excel to work in, you could do so in a new instance by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while starting Excel.
            [image: new instance]

I have posted code and a downloadable example of a countdown timer that displays the time remaining on a userform semi-independent of the Excel window, using the [Windows Timer API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx) (instead of Excel's procedure), in another **[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50724349/8112776)**.
                   [image: timer]

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible if the form is unloaded `Unload optionsForm`. But you can try to 'close' the form with `optionsForm.hide()` this only hides the form, the timer should keep running then.

The only way I see to calculate the time passed from a start time even if Excel is closed is to not save the start time in a variable `dteStart` but in an Excel cell.

Comment: Hi Peh, yes, I currently have a Close button for the userform that unloads it .... will test the hide... will it keep running if I close the excel file? .... right, doesnt work...

Comment: No! therefore you will need to use a Excel cell to save the start time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use a code that is placed in a module. The code is:

```
Option Explicit
Dim T

Sub stopTimer()
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime (T), Procedure:="Update", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub StartTimer()
T = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime T, "Update"
End Sub

Sub Update()
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = Format(Now - Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E11").Value, 
"hh:mm:ss")
UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = Format(TimeValue("1:00:00") - (Now - 
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E11").Value), "hh:mm:ss")
Call StartTimer
End Sub
```

Thereafter, you can now reference it in the userform by calling it. Here is a typical example. It is

```
Private Sub Userform_Activate()
Sheet1.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E11").Value = Now
Application.Run "StartTimer"
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K27").Value = "K29" Then
Me.CommandButton4.Caption = "Start"
Me.CommandButton2.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked very fine when we used it as a timer for my CBT which we just created.